# how to get average time in a column in hr:min format in r?

Tags: r

I have the datalike

```
mode       departure_time    activity_purpose
car            7:08            work
car            8:45            work
bike           6:34            school
walk           5:45            work
walk           6:20            school
```

how to calculate the average departure time for each activity purpose? And how to draw graph shows the departure time distribute? the y should be count and x should be departure time with format 5:00, 6:00, 7:00 etc.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

1. use `period_to_seconds` function from `lubridate` to get period element
2. `group_by` whatever you need: here you get the average departure_time of `activity_purpose` (you can adapt as you need)
3. `count`
4. to plot mutate to `dttm` element
5. plot bar chart

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tib1 <- tib %>%
  group_by(activity_purpose) %>% 
  mutate(average = seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hm(departure_time))))) %>% 
  count(average)

tib2 <- tib1 %>% 
  mutate(average_date_time = floor_date(Sys.time(), "1 day") + average)

ggplot(data=tib2, aes(x=average_date_time, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Output:

```
# Groups:   activity_purpose [2]
  activity_purpose average        n
  <chr>            <Period>   <int>
1 school           6H 27M 0S      2
2 work             7H 12M 40S     3
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help! Just another two question. is there any method to add color in bar graph and put note on side to illustrate which color present which purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing:

```
library(dplyr)
#Read in data
tib <- tibble::tribble(
  ~mode,       ~departure_time,    ~activity_purpose,
  'car',            '7:08',            'work',
  'car',            '8:45',            'work',
  'bike',           '6:34',            'school',
  'walk',           '5:45',            'work',
  'walk',           '6:20',            'school'
)
#Define function for mean time calculation
calc_mean_depart <- function(times){
  #Extract hrs from time
  hrs <- stringr::word(times, 1, sep = ':') %>% 
    #Convert to integer
    as.integer() %>% 
    #Convert to minutes
    magrittr::multiply_by(60)
  #Extract minutes
  min <- stringr::word(times, 2, sep = ':') %>% 
    #Convert to integer
    as.integer()
  #Get mean time in minutes
  mean_time <- mean(hrs + min)
  #Get the average number of hrs
  mean_hrs <- floor(mean_time/60)
  #Generate the output
  paste0(
    mean_hrs, ':', round(mean_time %% 60) ## Time mod 60 == minutes
  )
}
#Calculate group-wise mean time
tib %>% 
  #Group on activity
  dplyr::group_by(activity_purpose) %>% 
  #Get the mean
  dplyr::summarise(
    mean = calc_mean_depart(departure_time)
  )
#Output:
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  activity_purpose mean 
  <chr>            <chr>
1 school           6:27 
2 work             7:13
#Plot departure hr
tib %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    hrs = stringr::word(departure_time, 1, sep = ':'),
    hrs = as.integer(hrs)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(hrs))+
  ggplot2::geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```